# How to do contract RPC call?

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, pallet-contracts, substrate-contracts-node

I'm having trouble doing an RPC call using polkadot.js.

My contract is here: https://github.com/kanishkatn/ink-test/tree/master/flipper

I tried making the RPC call using the selector from metadata.json. But, it always throws this error

```
{
  gasConsumed: 0
  gasRequired: 0
  storageDeposit: {
    Charge: 0
  }
  debugMessage: 
  result: {
    Err: {
      Module: {
        index: 7
        error: 0x02000000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also wrote my own client, it throws the same error as well. My client is here: https://github.com/kanishkatn/ink-test/tree/master/client

The `instantiate` call works properly on polkadot.js/apps as well as contracts-ui. I'm able to call other methods in contracts-ui as well. So, clearly I haven't understood how the selector and the data works in `call`.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your gasLimit is too low. Increase gas limit or simply set it to -1 which will use max. gas available.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!